# Referring to another type defined in the same interface

Tags: typescript, types

```js
interface A {
    str: string;
    num: number;
}

interface B {
    key: keyof A;
    type: <?>;
}
```

What type should `type` be if I want it to correspond to the type in `A` that `key` points to, without `B` being generic?

---

I could make `type` be `A[keyof A]`, but then it won't match `key`.

I could also make `B` generic on `K extends keyof A`, then have `key: K` and `type: A[K]`, but I'd like to know if I can do this without `B` being generic.

Ideally, I'd like to create an object of type `B` and TypeScript would infer that if my object has a key `key` with the value `num`, then it must also have a key `type` with a value of type `number`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't ensure this with an interface, you can with a union, and you can generate the union from the interface with a mapped type:

```
interface A {
    str: string;
    num: number;
}

type B = {
    [P in keyof A]: {
        key: P;
        type: A[P]
    };
}[keyof A]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=11&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnIM5hQBc+hoA5gNw7IgCuAtifQwEbTUC+WWYAngAcUAIWQBeTDVwBtAArJQyANYQ+AexhoAuiWy59+lXxKzqBg-yElUcrVOScu0oxu1A)

`B` is equivalent to:

```
type B = {
    key: "str";
    type: string;
} | {
    key: "num";
    type: number;
}
```